# how to use Varela Round font with MikTex

Tags: miktex, fontfamily

Hi I would like to specify a specific font for my documentclass, Varela Round.

I am using MikTex and need to compile with PDFLaTeX only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a package to use it (I don't think there exists one). This means:

- making `.tfm` and, perhaps, `.vf` files
- converting the fonts to type1
- defining `.fd` and `.map` files for use with latex. Also a `.sty` file.
- install all these files in a local TeXMF tree, at the relevant places.
- mention the font in a local `updmap.cfg` and refresh the filenames database and the type1 fonts database.

All this can be done with the `lcdf type tools`. The `fontinst`  package will help. All details are explained in the `font installation guide`.

Comment: `.vf` files aren't required, though they are one possibility. Truetype fonts can also be used without conversion to type1.

Comment: Note that conversion can violate font licences (but I know nothing about these fonts, so maybe that's not a concern).