# Process to add a new font usable with LaTeX like fontawesome5

Tags: fonts

The package `fontawesome5` makes the font `awesome` usable in LaTeX via macros.

This package helps me to add some logo to listings. I would like to have more logos but to do that **I need to mimic the `fontawesome5` features**.

Can someone tell me what are the steps to follow ? I have no commercial tools but I can work on Linux.

Comment: There are free tools. You can take a look at the answer to this [recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512855/how-to-use-varela-round-font-with-miktex/512857#512857), for instance.

Comment: @projetmbc Do you already have a font  which you want to use in LaTeX or do you want to create a new one? Which engine (LuaTeX, XeTeX, pdfTeX, all of them)? Which specific features from `fontawesome5` do you want to mimic? IIRC most features there are pretty FontAwesome specific.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger My first idea is to use this webfont https://github.com/file-icons/icons/tree/master/dist . Is it easy to do ? Maybe this could be a new fontawesome like package. I would just like to have more logos for programming languages.

Comment: For Xe/LuaTeX, you can probably use `fontspec` if you can get the font into OTF or TTF format. For pdfTeX, you have more work to do. However, symbol fonts are among the most straightforward to setup, given type1 or TTF format. (If you are converting for pdfTeX, convert to type1 and you can use the stuff with TeX, too.) The Font Installation Guide shows one way to do it for type1.

Comment: See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide for information re. type1. TTF installation for pdfTeX can be done in the same way, but you have to reencode in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the links !